# Multivariable Calculus and Tangent to Plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :  (z+x^2)^3+(z+1+x^2+y^2)^5=e^{2x+y} +x+y\}$$

Find a unique real number $a$ such that $(0,0,a)\in S$.

Now I substituted $x=y=0$ and found $a$ to be $0$ as well.

What I'm concerned about is the next part of this question and it is as follows:

**Find an equation of the tangent plane to $S$ at $(0, 0, a)$, where $a$ was found in the first
question.**

I know that in order to get the equation of the tangent to the plane at this point i.e. $(0,0,0)$ I need to get it in the form $z=f(x,y)$ but how do I do that without expanding the above equation?

Comment: You need to get it in the form $f(x,y,z) = 0$ then apply the gradient to f to find a normal vector to the plane.

Comment: Why should I find a normal vector to the plane?

Comment: The plane is $r.n=r_o .n$ where $r=(x,y,z)$, $n$ is the gradient of f at $(0,0,0)$ and $r_0=(0,0,0)$. How else would you find the tangent plane?

Comment: I was thinking by moving everything to one side I will take partial derivatives with respect to x and y and then I will use this formula to find the equation of the tangent plane $$\begin{align*}z - f\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right) & = {f_x}\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)\left( {x - {x_0}} \right) + {f_y}\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)\left( {y - {y_0}} \right)\\ z & = f\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right) + {f_x}\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)\left( {x - {x_0}} \right) + {f_y}\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)\left( {y - {y_0}} \right)\end{align*}$$

Comment: You have no chance of isolating z though as you say. Using the gradient on $f(x, y, z)$ with the chain rule then putting $(0,0,0$ in will give you the normal vector to the surface at $(0,0,0$ so that you can then get the scalar equation of the plane. You can convert this to vector form easily then.

Comment: I don't completely understand what it is you are suggesting. Could you perhaps write a brief solution with some computations so I can understand it better?

Comment: Since the logic I'm trying to use is this: $\left( {{x_0},{y_0},{z_0}} \right) = \left( {{x_0},{y_0},f\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)} \right)$ I'm not using algebraic rules to separate $z$ with several computations but rather the formula that I have just mentioned...

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=(z+x^2)^3+(z+1+x^2+y^2)^5-e^{2x+y} -x-y=0$ so that $\underset{\scriptscriptstyle-}{\nabla }f$ at $(0,0,0)$ is $n=(-3,-2,5)$ and the tangent plane is $-3x-2y+5z=0$ at $(0,0,0)$

Comment: Ohhh I get this approach... Thank you so much!